# How to write a method that can return different data type based on enum as the parameter?

Tags: java, enums

I would like to define a method and by passing the enum, returns the mapped type based on the enum. So far I only work out this way:

```
public class Person {

    HashMap<String, Object> mData;


    void int getDetail(DetailInt detail){
        Object data = mData.get(detail.name());
        if(data instanceof Integer)
            return (int)data;
        return 0;
    }

    void String getDetail(DetailStr detail){
        Object data = mData.get(detail.name());
        if(data instanceof String)
            return (String)data;
        return "";
    }

}



public enum DetailInt {
    Age("age"), Weight("weight"), Height("height");

    String columnName;
    DetailInt(String columnName){
        this.columnName= columnName;
    }
}

public enum DetailStr {
    FirstName("first_name"), LastName("last_name");

    String columnName;
    DetailStr (String columnName){
        this.columnName= columnName;
    }
}
```

So I can use the same method, but passing different enums to get the data with the type.

```
int age = person.getDetail(DetailInt.Age);
String firstName = person.getDetail(DetailStr.FirstName);
```

Now, what I would like to achieve is to merge both enums together, so I can call as below:

```
int age = person.getDetail(Detail.Age);
String firstName = person.getDetail(Detail.FirstName);
```

It is neater. However, I have tried generic type and interface, still cannot find the way to do it. Use below way is similar to what I want but this is not enum type.

```
abstract class Detail {

}

class DetailStr extend Detail {

}

interface Details {
    DetailStr firstName = new DetailStr("first_name");
    DetailStr lastName = new DetailStr("las_name");
    DetailInt age = new DetailInt("age");
    DetailInt weight = new DetailInt("weight");
    DetailInt height = new DetailInt("height");
}

public class Person {

    void int getDetail(DetailInt detail){
        ....
    }

    void String getDetail(DetailStr detail){
        ....
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use one method to return different things? (I can't think of a reason to do this). Write a getter for each value!

Comment: why can't your method names be getIntDetail() and getStringDetail();

Comment: *Why* do you need that? It sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Java refuse to overload a method only by his return type

Comment: @AxelH you meant overloading. And you don't have to do that at all. Keeping method name same isn't required at all. Simply write methods as getIntDetail() and getStringDetail()

Comment: My example is not clear, because there are 100+ fields and I don't want to create all of them. Second, the field name will be stored elsewhere, and in the future it will be used to query the field I want.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar, yes of course ^^ it's monday.... thanks

Comment: @Arst Why not use reflection?

Comment: @Arst Also, why do you have so many fields? Does that come from a database? In that case there are plenty of tools that can automate the creation of pojos for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this in Java.

This is because a particular value of an enumerator has the same *type* as any other value of that enumerator. It's therefore not possible to construct an overloaded function since there's no type difference to act as a descriminator. (You cannot overload a function by return type difference alone.)

The obvious solution is to have two methods `getDetailAsInt` and `getDetailAsString`.

Comment: Where is the second reason come from ? I don't remember any restriction about the return types of overloaded methods to be related (well, everything "can be" Object after all ;) )

Comment: @AxelH `int` cannot be `Object`...but `Integer` can.

Comment: int cannot be an Object, it is a primitive type.

Comment: @Bathsheba, covariant return types applies to method overriding. Not sure you really meant overloaded functions.

Comment: I said `can be` not `is`, so the autowrapping permit everyting to become object. @PrasadKharkar, I guess he speaks about overring too.

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: You are completely correct. Of course an overloaded function can have a different return type, related or not. Let's put this down to my having a senior moment.

Comment: I should have added that having only different return types does not make them overloaded methods.Overloaded methods need to have different signature.  OP would have understood better

Comment: @PrasadKharkar: Done. Do feel free to answer accurately yourself - I'll be sure to upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I'll share this approach that does not use enums, but it might be of some use to you:

```
public class Key<T> {
    private String key;

    ...
}

public class Keys {
    public static final Key FIRST_NAME = new Key<String>("first_name");
    public static final Key AGE = new Key<Integer>("age");
}

public class Person {
    public <T> T getDetail(Key<T> key) {
        Object detail = mData.get(key.getKey());
        return (T) detail;
    }
}
```

I'm afraid it might not be possible to convert it to use enums, so you'd have to ensure no unwanted keys are created in some other way (package-private constructor etc.)